# How to get sum of meta_values of a meta_key in wp_query according to conditions

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

Here is my query args :

```
 $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'rented_properties',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            // 'fields' => 'SUM(amount_to_paid)',
        );


        $my_querys = null;
        $my_querys = new WP_Query($query_args);
```

My meta key is `amount_to_paid`, and I want to get the sum all the meta_values of this query condition. Please suggest your answer with `query_args`.

My Scenario : I have 1000 posts and each with meta_key amount_to_paid and it has some value. Now I filter 20 posts and want to get sum of meta_value of amount_to_paid . Did you got me now?

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about this, you should be calculating and updating this value whenever an `amount_to_paid` is added/changed, WP_Query retrieves posts, and that's all it does. It won't do calculations for you and it isn't SQL, you need to do those parts using the information WP_Query returns. Think of it as `WP_Post_Query` rather than `WP_SQL_Query`

Comment: Dear Tom, I have 1000 posts and each with meta_key  `amount_to_paid` and it has some value. Now I filter 20 posts and want to get sum of meta_value of `amount_to_paid` . Did you got me now?

Comment: I understand, but `WP_Query` won't calculate that for you, you need to grab the posts, then do the adding in an additional step, there's no argument you can add to `WP_Query` to get an answer from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query` gets posts from the database, but it's not a generic SQL query class, it should really be called `WP_Post_Query`, as `WP_Query` implies it can do any SQL.

As a result, you need to do several things:

1. Grab the posts you need
2. Get their meta values for `amount_to_paid` using `get_post_meta`
3. Add those values up using the basic PHP maths `+ - / * = += -=`

So:

```
$sum = 0;
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do the processing for each post
        $sum = $sum + get_post_meta( ... );
    }
}
echo esc_html( $sum );
```

Comment: I know we can do like this, but I think SQL query exectution is much much faster that PHP while loops for adding values. What you say?

Comment: These values all get cached by the internal WP_Cache system, so any other code that uses them will be sped up. Assuming you have an object store such as redis or memcache configured and setup. You should use the APIs and avoid raw SQL queries when possible

Comment: can you guide me how can I use WP_Cache?

Comment: In this case it's all happening behind the scenes, but if you want to store your own values, I'd suggest asking another question as it's a new subject. It's not difficult though, and a quick google will reveal the 2 basic functions you need

Comment: Where do you specify the post type?

Comment: @Amjad I didn't, `$query_args` contains the arguments for the query, you will need to provide your own arguments. Look up the official docs for WP_Query, they list all of the options with examples

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code.

```
global $wpdb;
$meta_key = 'link_click_counter';
$all_downloads = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
                                  SELECT sum(meta_value) 
                                  FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                                  WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key));

echo $all_downloads;
```

Comment: I can confirm this works as long as you declare `global $wpdb`.

Comment: The weakness/error here however is that you are counting values for all posts --- all post types, draft or published, public or private --- and cannot sort the unwanted out as in the accepted  (`WP_query` + loop) answer... So the OP has to adapt this answer by joining the table `$wpdb->postmeta` to `$wpdb->posts`, so the `WHERE` clause gets `AND post_type = 'rented_properties'` (and maybe also `AND post_status = 'published'`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer