# count post meta values

Tags: post-meta, count

I have a custom function to count downloaded times for a specific file attached  in the post,
but i want to display the count of whole post in my website

```
post meta = download_times
```

and how to skip time out error message ?

Comment: `I have a custom function to count downloaded times for a specific file attached in the post` - Is this function working?

Comment: the function works and it counts the file downloaded and updates the post meta for each post , but i want to count all post meta values to get the total downloaded from all posts !

Comment: You can adopt this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237610/how-to-get-sum-of-meta-values-of-a-meta-key-in-wp-query-according-to-conditions from @TomJNowell

Comment: If you have any problems just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You @prosti for your answer 
I made Thise small code based on your answer and it works for me

```
global $post;
$query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'cat' => 1,
            // 'fields' => 'SUM(amount_to_paid)',
        );

$sum = 0;
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do the processing for each post
        $sum = $sum + intval(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'download_counter' ));
    }
}
echo $sum ;
```